# custom click event on object (class Cell) only firing for the last cell whenever u click

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Hello everyone this is my first question here.
I have some problem in getting my custom created click event on cell class working properly. Until now it is notifying when the cell is clicked but it only shows that the last cell is clicked even if u clicked on the first one. Here is my code .

```
class Cell 
{
    public const int Width = 220;
    public const int Height = Width;
    public Point Position { get; set; }
    public string  Id { get; set; }

    public delegate void ClickEvent(object o);
    public event ClickEvent Click;


    public Cell()    
    {     

    }

    public void OnClick(Point p)
    {
        if (Click != null)
        {

            if (p.X - 220 < Position.X && p.X > 200 && p.Y - 220 < Position.Y && p.Y > 10)
            {
                Click(this);
            }

        }
    }

    public override string ToString() { return "Cell(" + row + "," + col + ")"; }
    }  


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Grid myGrid;
    Cell cell;
    private Point userPoint;
    Graphics g;
    int x = 200;
    int y = 20;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myGrid = new Grid();         
    }
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        userPoint = e.Location;
        cell.OnClick(userPoint);
        label1.Text = userPoint.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        DrawCrossingCells();
        myGrid.DrawAllCrossings(g,imageList1);
    }

    private void DrawCrossingCells()
    {

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            {
                cell = new Cell(row,col);                   
                g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue),x,y,Cell.Width,Cell.Height);
                cell.Position = new Point(x, y);
                cell.Id = (col.ToString() + row.ToString()).ToString();
                x += 220;
                cell.Click += cell_Click;               
            }             
            x = 200;
            y += 220;
        }
    }

    private void cell_Click(object sender)
    {
        Cell cc = (Cell)sender;
        Crossing cross = new Crossing(cc.Id);
        cross.Position = cc.Position;
        myGrid.AddCrossing(cross);
        MessageBox.Show(cc.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: the 'Is the Point inside the Cell?' section feels wrong somehow. Tried using a Rectangle? It looks like you're doing some maths to the Point that ultimately puts it somewhere else than where you've actually got it.

Comment: You mean the logic in the Onclick method inside Cell class ? cause i didnt get u .

Comment: I think the logic in the `Onclick` should be something like `if (p.X > Position.X && p.X < Position.X + Width && p.Y > Position.Y && p.Y < Position.Y + Height)`. Also in `DrawCrossingCells` you are resetting `x` to 200 so rows after the first will start 200 in. I think that should be `x = 0`.

Comment: The problem is that only the last created cell is listenning for the event and only this cell id is shown on the message

Comment: Ah, OK. You only have one `cell` object that is overwritten on each iteration of the loop in `DrawCrossingCells` so the last one is used in `Form1_MouseDown`.

Comment: Yes how to fix that :)

Comment: @user3804541 - sorry for the slow response, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one `Cell` object that is overwritten on each iteration of the loop in `DrawCrossingCells`. This means that the `cell` field only ever points to the last `Cell` created within the loop so when you do `cell.OnClick(userPoint);` you are always calling `OnClick` of the last created `Cell`.

You need to store each `Cell` object as you create it in `Form1`. A `List` for each `cell` in the row makes sense with a `List` of those `List`s per row. This would mean the line `Cell cell;` would become `List<List<Cell>> cells = new List<List<Cell>>();`. Inside your loop you can then populate the `cells` object with each `Cell` that you create.

In `Form1_MouseDown` you will need to work out which `Cell` has been clicked on and call `OnClick` on the correct one. This can be done by dividing `e.Location.X` by 220 (the cell width) and using that as the index to the inner `List` and dividing `e.Location.Y` by 220 (the cell height) and using that to index the outer `List`.

The code for the two changed methods would then be:

```
private void DrawCrossingCells()
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        List<Cell> rowCells = new List<Cell>();
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell(row, col);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), x, y, Cell.Width, Cell.Height);
            cell.Position = new Point(x, y);
            cell.Id = (col.ToString() + row.ToString()).ToString();
            x += 220;
            cell.Click += cell_Click;
            rowCells.Add(cell);
        }
        cells.Add(rowCells);
        x = 0;
        y += 220;
        }
    }

private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int row = e.Location.Y / 220; //divide by the Y size
    int column = e.Location.X / 220; //divide by the X size

    cells[row][column].OnClick(e.Location);
    label1.Text = e.Location.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Really helpfull thanks a lot, now I have another issue : I have a graph of at most 12 crossing every one of  them have 12 lanes . , could u propose me the best way to connect the proper lanes as neghbors. As proper i mean to connect lanes by id.The id has three letters- the first 2 letters are showing the crossing they belong to and the third is the actual number of the lane.The graph is two dimensional array(Matrix-12 crossings and 144 lanes)

Comment: @user3804541 - No problem. I think it's probably worth opening a new question for your other issue. I'll happily take a look at it. If this answer has solved your first issue it's possibly worth marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: That's fine - I'm pretty new here myself! Thanks.